# How to write Burmese text into CSV file android

Tags: java, android

I want to write Burmese text into `.csv` file. After writing Burmese text to a `.csv` file I open that file with `MS Office` but it does not show the Burmese text. 
A Burmese font is setup in my PC.
Below is my code:

```
OutputStreamWriter char_output = new OutputStreamWriter(new     

FileOutputStream(CSV.getAbsolutePath().toString()),
Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder());
char_output.write(message + str);
char_output.write("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(pList.get(i).getOrderNumber()).append(",").append(pList.get(i).getProductName()).append(",");
    sb.append(pList.get(i).getProductDiscription()).append(",").append(pList.get(i).getWeightKg()).append(",");
    sb.append(pList.get(i).getWeightViss()).append(",").append(pList.get(i).getQty()).append(",");
    sb.append(pList.get(i).getDate()).append("\n");
    char_output.write(sb.toString())`FileOutputStream(CSV.getAbsolutePath().toString() ),
}
char_output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Many would say, use a CSV library.

Instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()` it suffices to use `"UTF-8"`, but not wrong.

Instead of "\n" under Windows "\r\n" might be more convenient. (`System.getProperty("file.encoding")` would take Android's "\n".)

You need to handle commas and quotes. If a string value contains a comma, then it should be withing double quotes. Every inner double quote self-escaped, that is doubled.

Instead of a comma, also semi-colon is used. Even better is a tab character `"\t"`.

To detect UTF-8, you may write a BOM character at the begin of file. This is a zero-width space. BOM = Byte Order Mark, refering to UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE (reversed byte pair).

```
sb.append("\uFEFF"); // Add a BOM at the begin of file.
```

The file ending might be ".csv" but you may also lie, and give it an ending ".xls" to let Excel open it by double clicking.